# Interpreting Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geographically-weighted-regression

I have a question. As you know, we use Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) to discover the association between exploratory and dependent variables.
Now the question:
Do the standardized residual values (shown in red and blue graduated map) indicate a positive or negative association and the direction of this association ? ***Can it be concluded that where the standardized residual values are high and red, in these areas the correlation between the variables is positive and significant??** (I want only interpret the standardized residual values).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The high negative and positive StdResiduals are areas that the model poorly fits the data.  They do not indicate positive or negative association. See the ArcGIS documentation [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/interpreting-gwr-results.htm), where you will see the exact same map you included in your question.

The documentation states:

> (C) Examine the output feature class residuals.
>
> Over- and underpredictions for a well-specified regression model will
> be randomly distributed. Clustering of over- and/or underpredictions
> is evidence that you are missing at least one key explanatory
> variable. Examine the patterns in your OLS and GWR model residuals to
> see if they provide clues about what those missing variables might be.
> Run the Spatial Autocorrelation (Moran's I) tool on the regression
> residuals to ensure that they are spatially random. Statistically
> significant clustering of high and/or low residuals (model under- and
> overpredictions) indicates that the GWR model is misspecified.